# Does Specular Power affect the Brightness?

Tags: shaders, rendering, specular

I read the book *Real-Time Rendering, 2nd Edition*. Somewhere in there it say:

[image: real time rendring]

But I did the experiment and concluded that the m<sub>shi</sub> doesn't seem to affect to the brightness (it causes the area just to be narrower):

[image: power]

The experiment is base on http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut10.html.
Am I missing something? I didn't find an errata for the book on its corrections Website, and my first-languages isn't English, so maybe my vocabulary understanding is wrong?

Does the Shininess means the Brightness? Or what else?

Comment: "To shine" is to give out light but nowadays the word is also used to describe objects that reflect a lot of light, such as diamonds.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I eventually understand the Shininess is different from Brightness.

Because I misunderstood the shiny will increase the area of highlight before.

Actually, the more shiny will let the area of highlight become smaller.

So the below picture is more shiny than the above picture.

Sorry for asked a seemingly has nothing to do with programming problems.

Comment: Interestingly, there are cases where varying the specularity *will* affect brightness, namely when [working with physically-based shaders](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114378/39518) which conserve total energy between the diffuse and specular reflection. Increasing specular reflection in these cases decreases the brightness of the diffuse component.